# match zip code or address from php page to google map

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a PHP page in which address of some person fecth from database table.

Like:

```
Person name  address  zip     MAP

MR. xyz      city1    1234    click
MR. abc      city2    1234    click
MR. dfe      city3    1244    click
MR. rrr      city4    1284    click
```

If admin clicks on **click button** of **Mr. abc** then google map should be open with **address** or **zip** of **MR. abc** and google location should be open on google map of **MR. abc**

I don't have any idea how to do this? Please give some suggestion.

Now I found a code:

```
 <?php
include("connection.php");

 function geocode($address){

   // url encode the address
  $address = urlencode($address);

  // google map geocode api url
  $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}";

  // get the json response
  $resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

  // decode the json
  $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

    // response status will be 'OK', if able to geocode given address 
   if($resp['status']=='OK'){

    // get the important data
    $lati = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $longi = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    $formatted_address = $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'];

    // verify if data is complete
    if($lati && $longi && $formatted_address){

        // put the data in the array
        $data_arr = array();            

        array_push(
            $data_arr, 
                $lati, 
                $longi, 
                $formatted_address
            );

        return $data_arr;

    }else{
        return false;
    }

    }else{
    return false;
  }
 }


  if($_REQUEST){

   // get latitude, longitude and formatted address
   $data_arr = geocode($_REQUEST['address']);

    // if able to geocode the address
   if($data_arr){

    $latitude = $data_arr[0];
    $longitude = $data_arr[1];
    $formatted_address = $data_arr[2];

   ?>

    <!-- google map will be shown here -->
   <div id="gmap_canvas">Loading map...</div>
   <div id='map-label'>Map shows approximate location.</div>

   <!-- JavaScript to show google map -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
    </script>

    <?php

    // if unable to geocode the address
    }else{
    echo "No map found.";
   }
   }

   ?>

     But it gave an ERROR:  **Map shows approximate location.**
```

Is it right code or not?

Comment: Any existing code you can share? You'll need to make use of Google's Geocoding API to determine a location on a map, with PHP and/or JS

Comment: please read this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't have any code because I don't know how to start it?

Comment: This is a really common situation, you should be able to find a ton of examples / tutorials if you do a search for Google Maps API PHP, or check this out: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the address and zip in google map url and open it in new tab. The URL can look like this

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<address>+<zip>

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Delhi+110021
```

Comment: Thank you for reply

Comment: <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $address1; ?>" > But where to add zip code?

Comment: <a href="maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $address1,$zip; ?>" >

Comment: Showing results for cloudsoft technology, plot number 9, zone-1, mp nagar bhopal 462011. No results found for cloudsoft technology, plot number 9, zone-1, mp nagar bhopal462011.

Comment: <a href="maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo urlencode($address1 . ' ' . $zip); ?>" >